# Delphi pointer syntax

Tags: delphi, pointers

I have to pass an argument of the type `Pointer` to a function from an external DLL.

- How do I create a pointer to a procedure which I can then pass to the function?
- Can I also pass a pointer to a class member function to the external function, or will that not work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use `@MyProcedure` for that.

Beware that it has to have the right calling convention (probably `stdcall`).

You usually can't use a member function, because it has a hidden `SELF` parameter.

A `class` `static` method acts like a usual procedure/function though.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Methods

Answer (score 0):

Create this type if procedure (or function) is method

```
type
  TMyProc = Procedure(x:Integer;y:Integer) of Object;
```

or this

```
type
  TMyProc = Procedure(x:Integer;y:Integer);
```

if procedure is stand alone.

Usage:

```
//Some class method
Procedure TfrmMain.Add(x:Integer;y:Integer);
begin
  ...
end;

//Another class method that uses procedure as parameter
procedure Name(proc : TMyProc);
begin
  ...
end;

//Call with:

Name(Add);
```